Inconsistent State Synchronization with Custom useLocalStorage Hook in React
I'm encountering an issue with state synchronization in a React application using a custom useLocalStorage hook. The App component correctly logs changes to the counter state, while another hook trying to access the same state doesn't log these changes, even though the state is supposed to be shared via local storage.
codesandbox here
Here's the code:
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useLocalStorage = (key, initialValue) => {
  const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState(() => {
    try {
      const item = localStorage.getItem(key);
      return item ? JSON.parse(item) : initialValue;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to read from localStorage", error);
      return initialValue;
    }
  });

  const setValue = (value) => {
    try {
      const valueToStore =
        value instanceof Function ? value(storedValue) : value;
      setStoredValue(valueToStore);
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(valueToStore));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to write to localStorage", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleStorageChange = (event) => {
      if (event.key === key && event.newValue) {
        setStoredValue(JSON.parse(event.newValue));
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("storage", handleStorageChange);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("storage", handleStorageChange);
  }, [key]);

  return [storedValue, setValue];
};

const useCounter = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useLocalStorage("counter", 0);

  const incrementCounter = () => setCounter((prev) => (prev += 1));

  return { counter, incrementCounter };
};

const useInput = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const { counter } = useCounter();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect in useInput"); // this does not run as I type
  }, [counter]);

  return { input, setInput };
};

export default function App() {
  const { input, setInput } = useInput();
  const { counter, incrementCounter } = useCounter();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect in App"); // this runs as I type
  }, [counter]);

  const handleInput = (value) => {
    incrementCounter();
    setInput(value);
  };

  return <input onChange={(e) => handleInput(e.target.value)} value={input} />;
}

The App component correctly logs changes to the counter state, but the useEffect inside the useInput hook does not log these changes. I expected both useEffect hooks to be triggered when counter is incremented. Why is this happening, and how can I ensure the state is consistently shared and updated across components?

What you tried to do was smart, the local storage is something shared, so if we have 2 states based on local storage, then they would also be shared right? But that's not how it work. They are different states, when you change this doesn't reflect on the other. I only know 2 ways to have shared state, inside the same component like the example below or by using React Context
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useLocalStorage = (key, initialValue) => {
  const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState(() => {
    try {
      const item = localStorage.getItem(key);
      return item ? JSON.parse(item) : initialValue;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to read from localStorage", error);
      return initialValue;
    }
  });

  const setValue = (value) => {
    try {
      const valueToStore = value instanceof Function ? value(storedValue) : value;
      setStoredValue(valueToStore);
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(valueToStore));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to write to localStorage", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleStorageChange = (event) => {
      if (event.key === key && event.newValue) {
        setStoredValue(JSON.parse(event.newValue));
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("storage", handleStorageChange);
    return () => { window.removeEventListener("storage", handleStorageChange); }
  }, [key]);

  return [storedValue, setValue];
};

const useCounter = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useLocalStorage("counter", 0);

  const incrementCounter = () => setCounter((prev) => (prev += 1));

  return { counter, incrementCounter };
};

export default function App() {
  const { counter, incrementCounter } = useCounter();

  const useInput = () => {
    const [input, setInput] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log("useEffect in useInput");
    }, [counter]);

    return { input, setInput };
  };

  const { input, setInput } = useInput();


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect in App");
  }, [counter]);

  const handleInput = (value) => {
    incrementCounter();
    setInput(value);
  };

  return <input onChange={(e) => handleInput(e.target.value)} value={input} />;
}


I mean, technically you could use local storage to synchronize state, but you'd have to create a subscription that polls local storage looking for updates.  Very ugly.  Context/Global Store is the way to go.
